# How to sort SQL query result by $value in PHP associative array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sorting

I have an array which is the result of an SQL query. When I `print_r($results)` I get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q1] => 24 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q2] => 12 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q3] => 14 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q4] => 10 ) ) etc.
```

When I display contents in HTML with a `foreach ($result as $key=>$value)` loop, I get

```
-----------
|Q1 |   24|
|Q2 |   12|
|Q3 |   14|
|Q4 |   10|
-----------
```

But I'd like to sort the array by value so that I get

```
-----------
|Q4 |   10|
|Q2 |   12|
|Q3 |   14|
|Q1 |   24|
-----------
```

The second column is the product of a calculation, and not an actual DB column, so I can't use `ORDER BY` in the SQL. Here's the query itself:

```
SELECT (SUM(Q".$i.")) AS Q$i FROM marks
```

I've tried sort functions  - `arsort($results)` and others. I've tried reassigning to 2D arrays -  `$final_result[] = $results;` and sorting - but no luck.

Is there some trick I'm missing in my attempt to access the actual values in $results? (24, 12, 14 etc)

Comment: try with `usort`. though your php version should be `5.2+`

Comment: you want to sort by value and keep key associations, right? see http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php , i think its `asort`

Comment: Have you tried [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)? It does exactly what you need.

Comment: You could use `ORDER BY` inside your query

Comment: I've tried asort(). It doesn't work for this query result. My code would be:

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT (SUM(Q".$i.")) AS Q$i FROM marks");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
asort($results);
 foreach ($results as $result)
         { display results }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to sort the results of my query. It's a workaround.

The **problem** was that my query `SELECT FLOOR(SUM(Q".$i.")) AS Q$i FROM table` didn't yield an associative array that `asort(), usort()` etc could handle.

When I did a `var_export($results)` it output:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'Q1' => '24', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'Q2' => '12', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'Q3' => '14', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'Q4' => '10', ), )
```

Note the non-incrementing 0; this seems to be why the sort algorithms aren't working.

However, I *was* able to display the query results in a foreach loop without a problem to give:

```
-----------
|Q1 |   24|
|Q2 |   12|
|Q3 |   14|
|Q4 |   10|
-----------
```

So **my solution** was to reassign the query results to an associative array in that loop, as follows:

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
      { 
            foreach ($result as $key=>$value)
                { 
            $rankings["$key"]="$value"; 
            } 
          }
   }
```

Now, a `var_export($rankings)` reveals the data structure I would expect:

```
array ( 'Q1' => '24', 'Q2' => '12', 'Q3' => '14', 'Q4' => '10', )
```

And this new array *was* amenable to sorting:

```
asort($rankings);

-----------
|Q4 |   10|
|Q2 |   12|
|Q3 |   14|
|Q1 |   24|
-----------
```

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of `usort` (user-function sort), `strcmp` (string comparison) and `key` (for the variable keys) you can handle this:

```
$quarters = array(
    array(
        'Q1' => 24
    ),
    array(
        'Q2' => 12
    ),
    array(
        'Q3' => 14
    ),
    array(
        'Q4' => 10
    )
);

usort($quarters, function($a, $b) {
    return reset($a) - reset($b);
});

print_r($quarters);
```

Gives us:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Q4] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Q2] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Q3] => 14
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Q1] => 24
        )

)
```

Comment: The output doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: @axiac Could you elaborate please? OP requested help with sorting an array, whereby variable keys are sorted in descending order. That's what my code does.

Comment: Compare your output to the expected output describe in the question just below the sentence *"But I'd like to sort the array by value so that I get"*. Your code is a slower implementation of [`krsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php).

Comment: When I print_r($quarters) I get the output 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q4] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [Q3] => 14 ) [2] => Array ( [Q2] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [Q1] => 24 ) ). No sorting takes place. And I want to sort by *value*, not by key.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread the question. I have updated my answer. I will point out that the previous iteration was not a slower version of krsort as this is multi-dimensional array sorting, not single-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, Scoots. Thanks. I can see that sort() you supplied working fine when I run it.  But the array you declare is structured differently to the one my query generates . See how the [0] doesn't increment in Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q1] => 24 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q2] => 12 ) ). Could that be the problem?

Comment: Could you provide the actual array in valid PHP code please? The `print_r` sample you have provided doesn't look like you have only called `print_r` once to me.

Comment: If I do var_export($results); it outputs:

array ( 0 => array ( 'Q1' => '24', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'Q2' => '12', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'Q3' => '14', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'Q4' => '10', ), )